# Is it better to send to variables to a function instead of one?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

We are using a query to sort mysql results in php. I decided to use one variable and then break it into two when it reaches to query function from the front end. Bellow is the example of the code sort is equal to an example value being sent.

```
$sort = 'total_amount-ASC';  
$order = explode("-",$sort); 
if($order[1]=='ASC'){ 
    $query->orderAsc("'".$order[0]."'"); 
}else if($order[1]=='DESC'){ 
    $query->orderDesc("'".$order[0]."'"); 
}
```

Is this an acceptable way to send code from front end to a php script or should I be sending two separate variables?

Comment: This is an older version of the code. I have already gone ahead and remove the "'" in both queries since the $order[0] is a string.

Comment: it depends on how the variable `$sort` sent to the controller. Can you please show your code for the template .ctp too?

Comment: Hi the variable will always be a variation of total_amount-ASC or total_amount-DESC. It will never be null or blank.

Comment: Do not post older versions of your code, always post the _actual_ code that you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if the code is a good way to handle it, then my answer is no.  Simply because it would fail several unit tests:

- What if the order is not specified or even desired to be unspecified (suppose PHP could sort the raw results faster?)
- What about multiple sort criteria when that need arises?
- Is the user able to control the output case? Will 'asc' work as well as 'ASC'?

Probably a proper way to pass this would be an array,

```
Sort by: <select name="sort[]"> <option>City <option>State <option>Zip </select><br />
In <select name="order[]"><option value="">(none) <option value="ASC">A-Z <option value="DESC">Z-A </select>
```

Iterate your rows and then just sort through the field order by will always have a corresponding value even if it's blank. Very similar to the way desktop apps do it.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. The sort value is controlled and it will always receive a specific value. Unfortunately php can not be used to sort the values since the values will be sort when the query is made. Either total_amount-ASC or total_amount-DESC. There is no case for multiple sort criteria. The user is not able to control the output case.

Comment: You're welcome.  Based on this further information you have provided, your method is fine.  It sounds like you have a) limited application, b) limited authority over the process or system, or both.  But you should always think extensibility.  By definition you're introducing a business rule, and if that rule later binds you, then the cost might not be insignificant to change it depending on how embedded it is - especially with external inputs.

Comment: Also, as this does not have a definitive answer, I suspect it would be better placed in Code Review

Comment: @OliverWilliams No, example code is [off-topic at Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).